# SQL Query, join 4 tabelas, 2 group_concats + condicionais, Ajuda

Tags: sql, query, mariadb

Olá, criei uma query sql para retornar todos os dados do cliente em uma unica consulta, esta query funciona parcialmente caso todas as condicionais sejam  satisfeitas, porém este sistema utiliza o soft delete, no qual todos os registros não podem ser excluidos e apenas marcados como inativos. o campo status é marcado com Zero (0) para inativo e Um (1) para ativo.
as tabelas são:

```
tbl_cliente(id_cliente(pk),status,nome, etc...) 
tbl_endereco(id_endereco(pk),status,cliente_id(fk),logradouro, etc...) 
tbl_email(id_email(pk),status,cliente_email_id(fk),email, etc...)
tbl_telefone(id_telefone(pk),status,cliente_fone_id(fk), telefone, etc...)
```

e o relacionamento é 1 para muitos: 
um cliente tem/pode ter varios emails, telefones, endereços

a query:

```
SELECT 
    C1.id_cliente,
    C1.nome,
    C1.fones,
    C2.emails,
    C2.endereco,
    C2.numero
FROM
    (SELECT 
        cliente.`status`,
            cliente.id_cliente,
            cliente.nome,
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', telefone.telefone, telefone.tipo)) AS fones
    FROM
        cliente
    LEFT JOIN telefone ON telefone.cliente_fone_id = cliente.id_cliente
    WHERE
        telefone.status = 1
    GROUP BY cliente.id_cliente) AS C1
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        cliente.id_cliente,
            endereco.endereco,
            endereco.numero,
            GROUP_CONCAT(email.email) AS emails
    FROM
        cliente
    LEFT JOIN email ON email.cliente_email_id = cliente.id_cliente
    LEFT JOIN endereco ON endereco.cliente_id = cliente.id_cliente
    WHERE
        email.status = 1 AND endereco.status = 1
    GROUP BY cliente.id_cliente) C2 ON C1.id_cliente = C2.id_cliente
WHERE
    C1.status = 1;
```

eu preciso que a query busque os demais registros mesmo que o status de uma ou demais das condicionais não seja satisfeita. por exemplo:

se o cliente não tem nenhum email ou se os emails estão marcados como inativos a query não trás os outros registros das outras tabelas e é isso que eu estou tentando fazer. Estou usando o MariaDB.

[Dump da base](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ahg7feoc2ety5s5/pt%20stackoverflow%20com%20posts%2072191.sql?dl=0)

Comment: @gmsantos, grato pela correção!

Comment: Você quer selecionar todos os clientes ativos, independente se tenham emails ativos ou não?

Comment: Quero selecionar todos os dados do cliente, exceto os marcados como inativos, ou seja status = 0.

Answer (score 1):

Não faltou um parenteses?

```
SELECT 
    C1.id_cliente,
    C1.nome,
    C1.fones,
    C2.emails,
    C2.endereco,
    C2.numero
FROM
(
    (SELECT 
        cliente.`status`,
            cliente.id_cliente,
            cliente.nome,
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', telefone.telefone, telefone.tipo)) AS fones
    FROM
        cliente
    LEFT JOIN telefone ON telefone.cliente_fone_id = cliente.id_cliente
    WHERE
        telefone.status = 1
    GROUP BY cliente.id_cliente) AS C1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
        cliente.id_cliente,
            endereco.endereco,
            endereco.numero,
            GROUP_CONCAT(email.email) AS emails
    FROM
        cliente
    LEFT JOIN email ON email.cliente_email_id = cliente.id_cliente
    LEFT JOIN endereco ON endereco.cliente_id = cliente.id_cliente
    WHERE
        email.status = 1 AND endereco.status = 1
    GROUP BY cliente.id_cliente) C2 ON C1.id_cliente = C2.id_cliente
)
WHERE
    C1.status = 1;
```

Comment: mesmo com a adição do parenteses, se o endereço do cliente, por exemplo, estiver marcado com status 0 todo o resto dos dados não aparacem na consulta.

Comment: Substitui o inner join por um left join!

Comment: Alterei aqui a resposta

Comment: Obrigado @bruno

Comment: Obrigado @gmsantos,por indicar onde estavam os erros,

Comment: Consegui o resultado desejado, fazendo um SELECT com WHERE para cada tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui o resultado desejado, fazendo um SELECT com WHERE e LEFT JOIN para cada tabela de modo que cada condicional fosse respeitada e não aninhada como estava antes. Grato a todos que ajudaram, espero que esta resposta ajude mais alguem!

```
 
SELECT
    C0.id_cliente,C0.nome,C1.fones,C2.emails,C3.endereco,C3.numero
FROM(
(SELECT
    C.id_cliente,C.nome,C.`status`
    FROM cliente AS C
    WHERE C.`status` = 1) AS C0
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
    cliente.id_cliente,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', telefone.telefone, telefone.tipo)) AS fones
    FROM cliente
    LEFT JOIN telefone ON telefone.cliente_fone_id = cliente.id_cliente
    WHERE telefone.status = 1 GROUP BY cliente.id_cliente) 
    AS C1 ON C0.id_cliente = C1.id_cliente
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
    cliente.id_cliente,
    GROUP_CONCAT(email.email) AS emails
    FROM cliente
    LEFT JOIN email ON email.cliente_email_id = cliente.id_cliente
    WHERE email.status = 1 GROUP BY cliente.id_cliente) 
    AS C2 ON C0.id_cliente = C2.id_cliente
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT cliente.id_cliente, endereco.endereco, endereco.numero
    FROM cliente
    LEFT JOIN endereco ON endereco.cliente_id = cliente.id_cliente
    WHERE endereco.status = 1 GROUP BY cliente.id_cliente) 
    AS C3 ON C0.id_cliente = C3.id_cliente
)
WHERE
    C0.status = 1 AND C0.id_cliente =1 ;
```